# Display the image of the form in the popup using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to display the form details in a popup using php. When the user enters the details A popup has to be displayed where the details are displayed in a popup.. The details are displayed fine.. I want the image to be instead of text in the image field. I am unable to display image instead of text in the image field here is the code..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $title = $('#title')
  var $image = $('#image')
  var $filterDate = $('#filterDate')
  var $description = $('#description')

  $('#myForm').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // some other code
    // maybe disabling submit button
    // then:
   // $(form).submit();
   $('.title').text($title.val())
   $('.image').text($image.val())
   $('.filterDate').text($filterDate.val())
   $('.description').text($description.val())
   $( ".modalDialog" ).dialog();
  }
  });


});
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form method="post" align="center" id="myForm">
                                <div class="login">
                                    <div class="login-form">
                                        <h3>Title:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required/><br />
                                        <h3>Image:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" name="image" id="image"  required/>
                                        <br />
                                        <h3>Date:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" id="filterDate" name="date"  required/>
                                        <br />
                                        <h3>Description:</h3> 
                                        <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="description" id="description" required>
                                        </textarea>
                                        <br />

                                        <button type="submit" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>



                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>

<div class="modalDialog" title="Preview" style="display:none;">
 <span class="title" ><?php echo $_POST['title'] ?><br /></span></p>
  <p>Image :<span class="image"><img src="<?php echo $_POST['image'] ?>"/></span></p>
  <p>Date : <span class="filterDate"></span></p>
  <p>description : <span class="description"></span></p>


</div>
```

Comment: What is exactly is displayed for the image in the form?

Comment: what are you insert in input image... its url or any other text?
if its a url than it will display fine other wise image not display...
can you send me demo url

Comment: Add an image tag to the DOM where you want to display the image. I presume the value of the input tag 'image' is a url to the image? If so, just add an img tag and get the src attribute from the field value.

Comment: I send the url of the image in the image field in the form.

Comment: How can I add image tag to the DOM to display Image

Comment: You have already added image tag. Your url in form should point to some image in your server (or somewhere in internet). `<img src="<?php echo $_POST['image'] ?>"/>`